# PropertyGrid doesn't reflect attributes when object is received from referenced webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a custom class with properties in let's say `Project1`. These properties are accompanied by some standard attributes like `CategoryAttribute` and `DescriptionAttribute`. I want the values of these attributes to be shown in a PropertyGrid.

When I create the custom object and attach it to the `PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject` all the attributes' values are shown like expected.

Now when I move the custom class out of `Project1` and place it into an ASP.NET webservice and use a service reference in `Project1` all my attributes disappear and the PropertyGrid shows all the properties under the `Misc` category.

How can make the attributes visible and useable again in the PropertyGrid when using a webservice?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a service reference you will generate new classes that match the same serialization structure. Those new classed lack the attributes the original ones had.

What you can do:

1. Move your classes in a separate project that is referenced by both the server and the client code
2. When you generate the service reference check the option "Reuse types from referenced assemblies" or something similar named.

That way you will actually use the same types in both places.